# Updating elements in a ArrayList<List>

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm using a list of list as:

```
List<List<String>> LoL = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

I occasionally need to insert/edit the elements in the list. Is there a function that can refer to particular element in the 2d structure and insert the desired value there?

The only way I currently know to do this is a list at a time, using the get statement to refer to the existing list for rest of the elements along with the one to be inserted, as follows:

```
LoL.set(x, Arrays.asList(LoL.get(0).get(1), LoL.get(0).get(2), LoL.get(0).get(3)....LoL.get(0).get(12), "value to be inserted", LoL.get(0).get(14)...LoL.get(0).get(25));
```

and this gets cumbersome with even a moderately large number of elements.

Comment: You can use a `for` loop (a variant of the `while` loop) to insert multiple values at 'once'.

Comment: I am using a for loop, my problem is independent of that I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to set the inner list again and again. You can simply get the `List` at the required index and change any particular value in it by index using [List#set(index, element)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29), like this.

```
Lol.get(0).set(2, "SomeString");
```

Get the list at `index 0` and set the element present at the `index 2` to *"SomeString"*.

*Update:*

To update multiple elements in the same outer list, you can have a simple `for` loop and update the elements for the list you require. Something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < Lol.size(); i++) { // Iterate over Lol
    if(i == 2) { // If you want to update the elements of the List present at index 2
         // Do what you want - Below is just an example and isn't that very robust
        Lol.get(i).set(0, "String 1");
        Lol.get(i).set(3, "String 2");
        Lol.get(i).set(6, "String 3");
    }
}
```

*Note:* Using variable names starting with capital letters isn't the usual practice. Try to use the *camelCase*, if possible.

Comment: Awesome. This works. Is there a way to do this for multiple elements(in the same outerlist) in one go?

Comment: Ah, that wasn't really required, I just meant to ask if the syntax would somehow allow inserting multiple elements in one go. Thanks a bunch.